# HTML select required validation

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to validate `select` option but it's not working for me
this is my source code

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('dashboard/add_item') ?>

 <select name="provinsi_id" id='propinsi_id' required>
     <option value="0">-Select Category-</option>
     <option value="1">Graphics</option>
     <option value="2">Fonts</option>
     <option value="3">Prints Template</option>
  </select>

   <button type="submit" class="button big dark">Next<span class="primary"> Step</span></button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Where's your CodeIgniter code?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: html required in HTML not working for this source code

Comment: @chris85 please check again :)

Comment: Still you haven't asked any question... as it stands its unclear what you asking

Comment: So the question is about the HTML attribute `required`, not about PHP or codeigniter? You shouldn't rely on client side validation anyway.

Comment: what and how you trying to validate? with java script... if yes post here the code.. if not... so how?  why the fact you using codeigniter matter for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required` on a `<select>` will reject if the selected option has no value.

Try setting the value on the first option to "" instead of "0".

```
<option value="">-Select Category-</option>
```

Comment: i try like this but still not working
  <select name="provinsi_id" id='propinsi_id' required="">

Comment: Not what I mean. I mean <option value="">-Select Category-</option>